# How to unset delegate on UIView setAnimationDelegate: call?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, animation, uikit

I am receiving crash reports that appear to be from a UIView animation calling a delegate that has been dealloced.

```
    Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x334776f6 objc_msgSend + 18
1   UIKit                           0x31c566c4 -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:]
2   UIKit                           0x31c565d2 -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:]
3   QuartzCore                      0x30045a26 run_animation_callbacks
```

I am setting the current view controller as the delegate for animations using the following pattern:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
...
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

My question is, how do I set that delegate reference to nil in my dealloc method?  Is there some way to retain a reference to an animation?  Or fetch animations in progress?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CALayer class handles all animations for UIViews. You can access the UIView's layer using the `layer` property. If you were to replace the first argument of `[UIView beginAnimations: context:]` with an actual string, it would be possible to access that animation directly using CALayer's `animationForKey:` and `removeAnimationForKey:` methods.

In this case though, it might be enough to call `[view.layer removeAllAnimations]` before `dealloc` calls `[super dealloc]`. This will stop any custom UIView animations and, obviously, remove them from its layer.

Comment: Perfect!  Exactly what I was looking for.  I don't know how they overlooked the need to unset delegates for animations in the documentation, but we'll be requiring this pattern for safety anywhere animation delegates are set in our projects.