# iPhone Crash stack trace VS Crash report

Tags: iphone, crash, stack-trace, report

Just spent some time... on a crash, without understanding it. That's a classic:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00000010
```

Which leads me to a memory issue, addressing the invalid adress `0x10`

What bothers me is that I have crash report and stack trace, which differ:

---

**The crash report, sent by user (symbolicated successfully, that happens) :**

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000027d8 objc_msgSend + 16
1   UIKit                           0x0005e9d2 -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 54
2   QuartzCore                      0x0002d8c2 run_animation_callbacks(double, void*) + 286
3   QuartzCore                      0x0002d764 CA::timer_callback(__CFRunLoopTimer*, void*) + 116
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000567f4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 8
5   CoreFoundation                  0x000562a6 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 854
6   CoreFoundation                  0x0002779e __CFRunLoopRun + 1082
7   CoreFoundation                  0x00027270 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
8   CoreFoundation                  0x00027178 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
9   GraphicsServices                0x000045ec GSEventRunModal + 108
10  GraphicsServices                0x00004698 GSEventRun + 56
11  UIKit                           0x0000411c -[UIApplication _run] + 396
12  UIKit                           0x00002128 UIApplicationMain + 664
13  MyApp                           0x00003158 main (main.m:13)
14  MyApp                           0x00003120 0x1000 + 8480
```

---

**The crash stack trace (catched live by an Exception Handler)**

```
0   MyApp                               0x000d79c3 0x0 + 883139
1   MyApp                               0x000d790b 0x0 + 882955
2   libSystem.B.dylib                   0x302765d3 _sigtramp + 42
3   UIKit                               0x31eab9d9 -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 60
4   QuartzCore                          0x33a178c9 _ZL23run_animation_callbacksdPv + 292
5   QuartzCore                          0x33a1776b _ZN2CAL14timer_callbackEP16__CFRunLoopTimerPv + 122
6   CoreFoundation                      0x3084e7fb __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 14
7   CoreFoundation                      0x3084e2ad __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 860
8   CoreFoundation                      0x3081f7a5 __CFRunLoopRun + 1088
9   CoreFoundation                      0x3081f277 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
10  CoreFoundation                      0x3081f17f CFRunLoopRunInMode + 58
11  GraphicsServices                    0x31e445f3 GSEventRunModal + 114
12  GraphicsServices                    0x31e4469f GSEventRun + 62
13  UIKit                               0x31e51123 -[UIApplication _run] + 402
14  UIKit                               0x31e4f12f UIApplicationMain + 670
15  MyApp                               0x0000315f 0x0 + 12639
16  MyApp                               0x00003128 0x0 + 12584
```

Both differ, and the stack trace points to the crash in my code, but at addresses I can neither symbolicate nor identify. I think the crash report indicates that a message was sent to a released instance... Probably related to the use of :

```
+ (void)setAnimationDelegate:(id)delegate
+ (void)setAnimationDidStopSelector:(SEL)selector
```

So here (finally!) are my questions:

1. What explains the differences between logs? (libobjc.A vs libSystem.B ??)
2. Does the SIGBUS comes from my code or from UIKit?
3. How can I decipher the stack trace upper addresses (0x000d79??, which atos doesn't resolve)
4. Is that what I think, an issue related to an animation failing to end? similar to this > [How to unset delegate on UIView setAnimationDelegate: call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823575/how-to-unset-delegate-on-uiview-setanimationdelegate-call/2879230#2879230)
5. AFAIK, setAnimationDelegate is supposed to retain delegate... Someone to confirm?

**EDIT**: I can't use `NSZombiesEnabled`, this is a crash report from a published app, a crash that I didn't manage to reproduce on development environment. I just have these logs to diagnose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question, weeks laters, since I had no relevant answers, most are guesses, I wished I had more precise answers, but I guess my question was unclear :

1. Difference is coming from the origin of the log, a sighandler vs CrashReporter service, which are happening at different times, then the stack traces are slightly different.
2. SIGBUS comes from UIKit, but chances are big that's on a callback initiated from my code that ends on a released object. These kind of stack traces are a pain to debug when you can't reproduce the issue, since it basically tells you *"I'm crashing **somewhere** because of **an animation**"*, which one, where... I still didn't figured precisely. Could be anywhere, and also could be an Apple iOS bug.
3. The first addresses in the stack are just a *dead-end* where any SIGBUS stack-trace ends when a released object is called. They differs across compilations (versions), but are the same on any device, That's why they can't be symbolicated. (I would love to have a technical explanation of this, instead of my guess)
4. & 5. I guess I solved this bug byt being more "agressive" on canceling animations in certain cases like on deallocation of some Views...

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 5):

Whenever I see objc_msgSend at the top, my trust of the remaining stack is low, as the error that gives this tends to do bad things to the stack.

GuardMalloc is good for this since the attempt to do anything with deallocated space will crash the app immediately in the debugger.  The stack will be intact.  (This makes the app very slow, but it is a very powerful tool.)

The two stacks are the same up to the UIViewAnimationState method call.  The version that came from your exception handler is showing C++ mangled names instead of the regular names shown in the crash log.

(As I understand it) _sigtramp is the system's method of calling your signal handler and is short for Signal Trampoline.  The stack entries beyond that are probably your signal-handler code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, some valuable information in it :) About the stack entries beyond sigtramp, these are "default" adresses when you sent a message to a deallocated instance. As stated on other replies, no GuardMalloc was possible, that crash only occuring on a user device that I couldn't access. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Agreed, It is not possible for you to run GuardMalloc on the user's device.   However, you can run that exact code in the simulator with GuardMalloc, and if there is a flaw that results in a dangling pointer, you will find it when the code crashes.

Answer (score 2):

You should try NSZombie, to get information about what object you've released. This is a very useful tool when you get EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

To activate NSZombie do the following:

1. Get info of the executable.
2. Go to the arguments tab.
3. In the "Variables to be set in the environment:" section add:

Name: NSZombieEnabled
Value: YES

Then run your app as usual and when it crashes it should tell you which deallocated object received the message.

Comment: Thanks but I Know NSZombies... I just can't reproduce that bug and have a log.

Comment: @Erik I prefer to look for Zombies like so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190227/how-do-i-setup-nszombieenabled-in-xcode-4/8863063#8863063

Comment: @Besi This is an old answer for Xcode 3. It's expected to be outdated. Anyway, thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** I'm not 100% sure but I think the discrepancy is due to how the application is being run.  In the second log it looks like you're running the application via XCode in debug mode, a sigtramp signal has been sent to indicate a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

**2.** Your code - the error may come from the UIKit library but it's a result of a problem with your usage.

**3.** This is where NSZombieEnabled will make your life a lot easier!  If you run your application with the NSZombieEnabled flag set XCode will keep 'zombie' objects in place of deallocated objects.  When a zombie object is sent a message the process will trap the error and let you know exactly what object was sent the message.

If you're using XCode 4 enable NSZombieEnabled using the following instructions...

[How do I set up NSZombieEnabled in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190227/nszombieenabled-in-latest-xcode)

For older versions follow these instructions...

http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled

**4.** It does indeed appear that your animation delegate has been deallocated prior to the animation completing.

Comment: Same comment, i can't reproduce that bug and only have logs to diagnose. Editing question for clarifying this.